# Get application permissions of user

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook application (a two player game) that can post messages on the wall of a friend. This all works. But when the user opens the app for the first time he gets a message asking him if he allows the application to post messages on his wall.

Obviously some users will press the "Don't allow" button.

Is there a way to check the permissions that my ap has with a certain user? So i know wether or not to call the facebookClient.Post() method.

I'm using the C# FacebookClient library. So if possible i'd like a solution for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course, there's the *permissions* connection for the [User object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/), and you don't need any special permission for asking that.

You can ask about the logged in user "me/permissions" or by user id "USER_ID/permissions", which will return:

> array containing a single object which has the keys as the permission
>   names and the values as the permission values (1/0) - Permissions with
>   value 0 are omitted from the object by default

You can try it with the [Graph Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/permissions).

I have no idea about the C# part, but since all facebook SDKs are simply wrappers for https requests, I'm sure it's possible. Basically, if you can get results for "/me" then you should be able to get results for "/me/permissions".